# Semantic Credits with Photos on a site

Tags: html, semantics

I am trying to find this out but I haven't found anything yet. What is the correct way to semantically associate Credits with a Photo on a website using HTML 5? I have heard people say that the `cite` tag is used for this, but after reading the W3C specs, I don't think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend the `small` element. See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element

Comment: Heh. Nice find, @Palpatim. I've always just used it to get small text (though I rarely actually use it).